# C# - What is the most efficient way to generate 10 character random alphanumeric string in?

Tags: c#, string, random

What is the most efficient way to generate 10-character random alphanumeric string in c#?

Comment: And why/how does it have to be most efficient? Does it have to be cryptographically safe? Are collisions OK ?

Comment: That, and how random do you want?  A random number generated with code isn't really random.

Comment: You could buy a CD with files full of random numbers and just read another one from a file when you need it. I say this in jest, but it does exist. http://www.westphal-electronic.com/z_cd_eng.htm

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can I create an unique random sequence of characters in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1275492/how-can-i-create-an-unique-random-sequence-of-characters-in-c)

Comment: Henk is right -- saying "most efficient" is a complete non-starter. If you have performance requirements then *state your requirements*. Say that you need to be able to generate one such string in less than five microseconds or ten thousand such strings an hour, or whatever your actual constraint is.

Comment: You have accepted a dangerously incorrect answer. Guids are not *guaranteed* to be *random* for any definition of "random". Guids are guaranteed to be *unique*. GUID stands for "Global Unique IDentifiers", not "Random Identifiers".  **Do not use guids as a source of randomness and do not use a fragment of a guid as a source of uniqueness**. Guids are not random, and they are not unique unless you take the whole guid. (You cannot take half an airplane and expect it to be the half that flies.)

Comment: What range of characters? Just latin alpha-numeric (ASCII subset) or all Unicode letters and numbers?

Comment: -1: incomplete problem statement

Answer (score -5, accepted):

Guid is pretty fast

```
Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(0, 10);
```

[From MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.guid.aspx)

> A GUID is a 128-bit integer (16 bytes) that can be used across all computers and networks wherever a unique identifier is required. Such an identifier has a very low probability of being duplicated.

It might not be unique for a billion requests since you need only 10 characters. But it generates a string from 0 to 9 and A to F.

---

### Performance

Tested using

```
public static void Test(Action a)
{
    Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();

    for (var i = 0; i < 10000; ++i)
        a();

    sw.Stop();

    Console.WriteLine("ms: {0} ticks: {1}", sw.ElapsedMilliseconds, sw.ElapsedTicks);
}
```

#### Guid method

```
Test(() =>
{
    var xxx = Guid.NewGuid().ToString("N").Substring(0, 10);
});

// Result
// 6     ms
// 17273 ticks
```

#### Bytes method

```
Test(() =>
{
    var buffer = new byte[5];
    new Random().NextBytes(buffer);
    var x = string.Join("", buffer.Select(b => b.ToString("X2")));
});

// Result:
// 57     ms
// 165642 ticks
```

It is up to you to pick between `high speed` or `high reliability`.

Comment: A GUID is not a random number and if you substring it is not necessarily even going to be unique

Comment: Would it really be faster than Random.GetBytes?

Comment: -1: like @Dustin says, a GUID is not a random number and most likely will not be very unique

Comment: -1: Do we know exactly what goes into those first bytes of a Windows-generated GUID?

Comment: Currently windows uses a class 4 GUID, for which it is well know which bits are random, and which are fixed. But of course windows can switch the algorithm at any time.

Comment: @Henk: in general a *random* number does not have to be unique by all means.

Comment: @Tim: I know but 4 out of 5 "how to create  random code" questions here confuse the two.

Comment: But seriously, the first N positions of a GUID is horribly non-random: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2008/06/27/8659071.aspx. A simple RNG (System.Random comes to mind) wins any day and is easier to use

Comment: @sehe that blogpost describes a different kind of GUID creation algorithm than the one currently in use. The current implementation is indeed random for most bits. Of course using a GUID as RNG is still a bad idea.

Answer (score 6):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.path.getrandomfilename.aspx

```
string randomName = Path.GetRandomFileName();
randomName = randomName.Replace(".", string.Empty);

// take substring...
```

eg:

```
?Path.GetRandomFileName();
"rlwi1uew.5ha"
?Path.GetRandomFileName();
"gcwhcoiy.vxl"
?Path.GetRandomFileName();
"2pzyljzf.k41"
?Path.GetRandomFileName();
"kyjzcccf.d3c"
```

Comment: You can squeeze out a tiny bit more performance by using `.Remove(8, 1)` instead of `Replace`

Comment: Given that we don't know from the question if the result should be cryptographically safe, collision-proof (within or between threads) etc. this answer is the safest bet.

Answer (score 3):

```
var buffer = new byte[5];
new Random().NextBytes(buffer);
Console.WriteLine(string.Join("", buffer.Select(b => b.ToString("X2"))));
```

Comment: Or new RNGCryptoServiceProvider.GetBytes(buffer);

Comment: This breaks if called in quick succession(i.e. twice within a few milliseconds) since you create an instance of `Random` on each request.

Answer (score -2):

```
var buffer = new byte[15];
new Random().NextBytes(buffer);
string rnd = Convert.ToBase64String (buffer).Substring (10);
```

The only problem I see with this is that it also uses `+` and `/`, so you'll have to replace them with something, too.

```
string rnd = Convert.ToBase64String (buffer)
   .Substring (10)
   .Replace ('/', '0')
   .Replace ('+', '1');
```